# How to move Activity by clicking Image Kotlin Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I am new at kotlin.
I got a problem moving to another activity. I don't know how to use an ImageView to move to another activity.

Here is my Main Activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
private lateinit var rvFood: RecyclerView
private var list: ArrayList<Food> = arrayListOf()

//Main
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    rvFood = findViewById(R.id.rv_food)
    rvFood.setHasFixedSize(true)

    list.addAll(FoodData.listData)
    showcardFood()

    //Here my target Image
    val moveDetail: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.item_photo)
    moveDetail.setOnClickListener(this)
}
//CardView
private fun showcardFood(){
    rvFood.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val cardFoodAdapter = CardFoodAdapter(list)
    rvFood.adapter = cardFoodAdapter
}

//About
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.about,menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
//Move Activity
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.nav_about ->{
            val moveIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, About::class.java)
            startActivity(moveIntent)
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when(v?.id){
        R.id.item_photo->{
            val moveDetail = Intent(this@MainActivity, Detail::class.java)
            startActivity(moveDetail)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry if I have a made mistake, as this is my first post.

Comment: Is imageView enable by setting "imageView.isEnabled = true"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to perform click event by list item of recycler view.
in that case, you need to set a listener from ViewHoler of recycler view's adapter class.